# In R, is there a way to identify similar string values in two columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, subset, data-manipulation

I have a large dataframe with 70,000 observations with column A and column B having pairs of nurses and physicians who worked together the same shift. Unfortunately there are some observations here and there (I can't quite gauge how many but it's a minority) where they are the same person in column A and column B but their names are spelled slightly differently because of the addition of a middle name or a nickname in one column but not in the other. I want to create a dataframe that ONLY has those rows. Is there a way to use a %like% and which function or something similar to identify all of these rows?

Here is an example of what I have:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Jimmy Fallon | Harry Potter |
| Jimmy Fallon | James Fallon |
| Harry Potter | John Oliver |
| Harry Potter | Harold Potter |

What I want:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Jimmy Fallon | James Fallon |
| Harry Potter | Harold Potter |

Comment: Two approaches: if the misspellings or alternations are known you can create a lookup list and then continue with matching. If not, your best shot is measuring the string distance (check package stringdist) although it might not work well with additional middle names.

Comment: check also `adist` which is included in R (utils)

Comment: Check out this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775224/using-grepl-in-r-to-match-family-and-given-names-from-list-of-co-authors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option is to use `adist` then `filter` to the rows that have a low distance. This method kind of assumes that there is a common element in each column (e.g., the last name).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(adist(x=A,y=B,ignore.case=TRUE) <= 3)
```

**Output**

```
  A            B            
  <chr>        <chr>        
1 Jimmy Fallon James Fallon 
2 Harry Potter Harold Potter
```

Or with base R:

```
df[subset(t(t(mapply(adist, df$A, df$B))) <= 3),]
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("Jimmy Fallon", "Jimmy Fallon", "Harry Potter", 
"Harry Potter"), B = c("Harry Potter", "James Fallon", "John Oliver", 
"Harold Potter")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

**Determining Cutoff**

You might need to change the cutoff filtering value depending on your data. However, you could get the distance and find where your best cutoff would be when names are slightly misspelled.

```
df2 <- data.frame(A = c("Jimmy Fallon", "Jimmy Fallon", "Harry Potter", "Hary Poter"), 
                 B = c("Harry Potter", "James Fallo", "John Oliver", "Harold Potter"))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dist = adist(x=A,y=B,ignore.case=TRUE)) %>%
  as.data.frame %>% 
  arrange(dist)

             A             B dist
1 Jimmy Fallon   James Fallo    4
2   Hary Poter Harold Potter    4
3 Harry Potter   John Oliver    9
4 Jimmy Fallon  Harry Potter   10
```

So, now we know that 4 would be a better cutoff for filtering.